# jquery scrolling effect in two column

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I m using fiddle link to move one div upward direction and second div in downward direction at the same time .

For left column  its working fine but  I want same functionality for right column

I am using this link

```
[example][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the same with the right col what you did with the left:

```
$("#right").on("scroll", function () {
    var scrolledleft = parseInt($("#right").scrollTop()) * -1;
    console.log(scrolledleft + scrolledright)
    $("#left").scrollTop(scrolledleft + scrolledright)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/noh1jogv/

**Edit:** Firefox seems to trigger `scroll` event when using `scrollTop` programatically. That means that a scroll in the left `div` triggers `scroll` in the right `div` and vice versa. To avoid this use an additional varialbe `preventEvent`:

```
var preventEvent = false;
// Add event listener for scrolling
$("#left").on("scroll", function (e) {
    if(preventEvent) {
        preventEvent = false;
        return;
    }
    preventEvent = true;
    var scrolledleft = parseInt($("#left").scrollTop()) * -1;
    $("#right").scrollTop(scrolledleft + scrolledright);
});

// Add event listener for scrolling
$("#right").on("scroll", function (e) {
    if(preventEvent) {
        preventEvent = false;
        return;
    }
    preventEvent = true;
    var scrolledleft = parseInt($("#right").scrollTop()) * -1;
    $("#left").scrollTop(scrolledleft + scrolledright)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/noh1jogv/2/

Comment: I tested it in chrome and IE. It works fast and fluid for me.