# Scroll in two columns with one link

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, multiple-columns

I'm a novice and I want to scroll in two separate columns of different height with only one link.

I figure it out with a simple ScrollTop function but the problem is if I click on a project title/link and then on an other one the Scroll is not right : it goes not on the good spot.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".projet1").click(function() {
    $(".container_droite").animate({ scrollTop: $("#projet1_txt").offset().top-90 },800 );
    $(".container_gauche").animate({ scrollTop: $("#projet1_img").offset().top-160 },800 );
  });

$(".projet2").click(function() {
    $(".container_droite").animate({ scrollTop: $("#projet2_txt").offset().top-90 },800 );
    $(".container_gauche").animate({ scrollTop: $("#projet2_img").offset().top-160 },800 );
  });

$(".projet3").click(function() {
    $(".container_droite").animate({ scrollTop: $("#projet3_txt").offset().top-90 },800 );
    $(".container_gauche").animate({ scrollTop: $("#projet3_img").offset().top-160 },800 );
  });

$(".projet4").click(function() {
    $(".container_droite").animate({ scrollTop: $("#projet4_txt").offset().top-90 },800 );
    $(".container_gauche").animate({ scrollTop: $("#projet4_img").offset().top-160 },800 );
  });
});
```

I know it's not very clean, but  I'm very bad with functions, so I try with what I know.
I'm assuming I need a return something but I don't know how to do.

Thank you !

Comment: Read this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409441/jquery-scrolling-effect-in-two-column

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't understand how to use this topic in my case (sorry)